# Erroneous and mysterious character substitutions in HTTP requests

Tags: lamp, google-chrome

I'm seeing weird requests from a user that seems to be legit otherwise. Basically, it seems like some characters in the request their browser makes are replaced, seemingly at random. From my apache2-logs:

```
wdomain.com:80 A.B.C.D - - [01/Jul/2015:14:21:05 +0200] "POST /index.php?id=699&dID=foo HTTP/1.1" 301 608 1822125 "http://www.vdomain.se/my-profile/private-messages/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTLL, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36"
```

or instance, here `dID` should be `eID`. `vdomain` in the referrer should be `wdomain`. And `KHTLL in the user-agent should be`KHTML`` of course!

```
wdomain.com:80 A.B.C.D - - [01/Jul/2015:14:21:11 +0200] "GET /my-profile/private-messages/?dID=foo HTTP/1.1" 404 24471 541869 "http://wdomain.com/my-psofile/private-messages/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac NS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36"
```

here `my-profile` in the referrer has been switched to `my-psofile`.

What could cause these seemingly random substitutions? It seems like a rouge extension could be ruled out, since some substitutions should not come from changes in the DOM, such as the change in referrer and user-agent. Since the user seems benign otherwise, and since the changes are so random, it seems unlikely to be any malicious intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably something intercepting and mishandling the traffic between the client and you.    You may want to use Tcpdump or similar to see the actual packets being received on the wire to make sure the problem isn't an Apache module rewriting the request in a weird way.

If you can intercept the clients packets as they leave their machine that might also tell you if the problem is being generated on their side (maybe a browser plugin), or a man in the middle - like a proxy.

Comment: Talking with the user, it seems that they know they're having some kind of problems with their connection. They say they have problems with other sites as well. I'm closing this case, since the error is not on my side.